# RE2 regular expressions on streams?

Tags: regex, re2

Is it possible to use Google RE2 with streams? Some input literals that we are suppose to process with regular expressions can potentially be too large to hold in-memory.

Comment: I don't think so. However, since it is [open source](http://code.google.com/p/re2), go ahead and hack it to support this :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a maximum match length, you could read the data in blocks of at least twice that length. If the match fails, or starts less than that many characters from the end, cut the current string, and append another block.

The length of the match string would never be more than the block length + max match length.

**Example in C#:**

```cs
public static IEnumerable<StreamMatch> MatchesInStream(
        this Regex pattern, TextReader reader,
        int maxMatchLength, int blockLength)
{
    if (maxMatchLength <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be positive", "maxMatchLength");
    }
    if (blockLength < maxMatchLength)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be at least as long as maxMatchLength", "blockLength");
    }

    char[] buffer = new char[blockLength];
    string chunk = "";
    int matchOffset = 0;

    // Read one block, and append to the string
    int charsRead = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockLength);
    chunk += new string(buffer, 0, charsRead);

    while (charsRead > 0 && chunk.Length > maxMatchLength)
    {
        int cutPosition = 0;
        foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches(chunk))
        {
            if (match.Index > chunk.Length - maxMatchLength)
            {
                // The match could possibly have matched more characters.
                // Read another block before trying again.
                break;
            }

            yield return new StreamMatch(matchOffset, match);
            cutPosition = match.Index + match.Length;
        }
        cutPosition = Math.Max(cutPosition, chunk.Length - maxMatchLength);
        matchOffset += cutPosition;
        chunk = chunk.Substring(cutPosition);

        charsRead = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, blockLength);
        chunk += new string(buffer, 0, charsRead);
    }

    // Stream has ended. Try to match the last remaining characters.
    foreach (Match match in pattern.Matches(chunk))
    {
        yield return new StreamMatch(matchOffset, match);
    }
}

public class StreamMatch
{
    public int MatchOffset { get; private set; }
    public Match Match { get; private set; }

    public StreamMatch(int matchOffset, Match match)
    {
        MatchOffset = matchOffset;
        Match = match;
    }
}
```

```
// One horrible XML parser
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var pattern = new Regex(@"<(/?)([\w:-]{1,15})([^<>]{0,50}(?<!/))(/?)>");
foreach (StreamMatch match in pattern.MatchesInStream(reader, 69, 128))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but what if the regular expression want to match if "starts with this character and ends with this character", ex. `/^[x-y](\w*)[x-z]$/` ?

Comment: Put a range-limit on the middle, even if it is large. `/^[x-y](\w{0,400})[x-z]$/`

Comment: The problem is that the regex's are user generated, so we can't really predict what kind of matches they want. Only way to solve this would be a stream-oriented regular expression processor I believe. Thanks though.

Comment: Your solution can yield matches which are longer than the max length we set. We need to check for the match length and reduce the chunk until we find a match that is not longer than the max length on it. The algorithm for this does not seem trivial. There are regex engines which support streaming. I think it is possible without having a max length, since all you need to store in memory is the beginning of the match and the next part of the pattern that should be matched. I don't think backtracking can be supported that way,but still better than nothing. https://github.com/google/re2/issues/251